# Xamarin.forms how to convert string to Page

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

This is my code in the ViewModel

```
  async Task ExecuteMenu(object obj)
        {
            Page page = new Page();
            System.Reflection.Assembly asm = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            Type t_form = asm.GetType(asm.GetName().FullName + "." + obj.ToString());
            page = Activator.CreateInstance(t_form) as Page;


            try
            {
                await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new page());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            }
            finally
            {

            }
        }
```

I have a menu elements loading from Command. In obj i pass string who contains the name of the selected contentpage. I dont know how to convert string name into page object name . This code doesn't work. I'm trying to dynamically call pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
         var pageType= Type.GetType($"NamespaceOfYourView.{obj}");
         var page = Activator.CreateInstance(pageType) as Page;
         await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(page );
```

Comment: It working fine. Is this tipe of define is good on performance? My idea is to dynamically  call pages. I dont have a lot about 10 pages maybe . Are there any faster solution?

Comment: @VaskoJosifovski I used this on my own project and I have 6-7 pages. Cannot face any performance problems yet. If you want to gets the type with the specified name you need do it like this. You can read details of Type.GetType in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.gettype?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Type_GetType_System_String_).

Answer (score 0):

Replace `asm.GetName().Name` with `asm.GetName().FullName` ;

#### Output

**GetName().Name** :   "yournamespace"

**GetName().FullName**  :  "yournamespace, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"

Obviously , `Name` string is the correct one .